# Rotating a table, td's in a jquery list

Tags: javascript, jquery, rotation

I'm looking for a similar styled plugin like the Rotating Tweets available on WordPress.

Basically I want the list to to cycle through just like the rotating tweets does, but it's not a twitter feed.

[Demo of what i'm after (on the right hand side)](http://www.martintod.org.uk/2012/05/29/new-twitter-plugin-to-show-tweets-in-rotation/)

If anybody knows of any jquery or similar plugins, please can you let me know.

Comment: The answer is hidden on the page. Just before the yellow block: All this was only possible due to the good people of WordPress, the Twitter API, jQuery and jQuery Cycle http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/ I'd say you need neither Wordpress nor Twitter API;-)

Comment: Cheers mainguy, I missed that bit! I'm not using WordPress on this site, I just like the way it rotates through.  I take it I can just rip out the bits I don't need then.